# WSL upgrade issue with Python311.dll

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade` in WSL yields a System Error stating that python311.dll was not found. This occurs when the system tries to update python3-pip packages.

Also calling python3 and pip yields the same error.

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPE0Y.png)

I have tried:

- Repairing and restarting WSL from System settings.
- Re-downloading python311.dll + pasting into C:\Windows\System32
- Re-downloading Python via Microsoft Store and Python.org
- Updating Environmental variables + $PATH
- `sudo apt purge python3-pip`
- `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- Holding python3-pip from upgrading